# How do I check for and resolve collisions within FixedUpdate using a kinematic rigidbody?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have been working on my own kinematic character controller for a while, but only recently learned that one should consider updating its position and rotation using `Rigidbody.MovePosition` and `Rigidbody.MoveRotation` instead of directly modifying the `Transform` component, which is what I am doing now. While my controller works fine, and does not cause any noticeable performance impact in my small games, I want to better understand the benefits of manipulating the `Rigidbody` component, and especially how this all works within `FixedUpdate` instead of `Update`.

To be clear about the supposed impacts on performance, Unity's [manual on 2D rigidbodies](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-Rigidbody2D.html) says:

`Any Collider 2D component added to the same GameObject or child GameObject is implicitly attached to that Rigidbody 2D. When a Collider 2D is attached to the Rigidbody 2D, it moves with it. A Collider 2D should never be moved directly using the Transform or any collider offset; the Rigidbody 2D should be moved instead. This offers the best performance and ensures correct collision detection.`

Right now, my basic controller loop looks like this in the `Update` method:

1. Read the user's input velocity
2. Modify the controller's velocity based on this input (this velocity is distinct from `Rigidbody.velocity`)
3. Using `Physics` queries, sweep the controller's body against the appropriate collision layers by `velocity * Time.deltaTime`
4. Pick a collision resolution position based on a set of rules
5. Set the controller's `Transform.position` to this resolution position

I also have a method that moves the controller using `Transform.Translate` if no collision detection is needed.

As you can see, though my controller GameObject has a kinematic rigidbody attached to it, I never actually use it for anything. Unity's documentation on kinematic rigidbodies is conflicting, stating [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/2021.3/Documentation/ScriptReference/Rigidbody2D.MovePosition.html):

`Note: MovePosition is intended for use with kinematic rigidbodies.`

but also [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/2021.3/Documentation/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-isKinematic.html):

`If isKinematic is enabled...The rigidbody will be under full control of animation or script control by changing transform.position`

I am also unsure about how to manually check for collisions within `FixedUpdate`, as I have read that `FixedUpdate` can be called more than once per frame. Frankly, I thought `FixedUpdate` was only supposed to be used with dynamic rigidbodies to simulate real physics, and thus have only used this method for simple manipulation of those kinds of rigidbodies.

And then `Rigidbody.MovePosition` states that

`2D rigidbodies have a fixed limit on how fast they can move therefore attempting to move large distances over short time-scales can result in the rigidbody not reaching the specified position during the next physics update. It is recommended that you use this for relatively small distance movements only.`

What if my character needs to move a very large amount? Do I just set `Rigidbody.position` directly?

I guess I am trying to figure out how I can reconcile all of this logic to conform to what Unity says is best for performance. Perhaps I need to combine `Update` and `FixedUpdate`, but ultimately I am just hoping to receive some clarification and guidance regarding all of this.

Comment: If you intend to set `Rigidbody.isKinematic = true` for the life of the rigid body and corresponding game object(s) and control movement yourself, then I would probably get rid of the rigid body entirely.  `isKinematic` is there should you wish to turn it on _temporally_ otherwise it defeats the purpose.  _["Kinematic rigidbodies are also particularly useful for making characters which are normally driven by an animation, `but on certain events` can be quickly turned into a ragdoll by setting isKinematic to false."](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-isKinematic.html)_

Comment: ...collisions, bouncing and forces is kinda a big problem to solve, best _let Unity do what it does best._  As you have discovered, doing physics in code requires great care and must be done from certain stages in the Unity pipeline else that bouncing ball might end up on the moon! ;)

Comment: @MickyD if you still want to track collisions for that object it might require a `Rigidbody` though since at least one of the two colliding objects has to have one

Comment: `FixedUpdate` is simply the next physics update .. you don't have to activily use it but basically all phyics and collision detection happens within that loop, not in `Update`

Comment: Using `Rigidbody.MovePosition` would be basically telling Unity's physics system to do the things you're doing manually to resolve the next position automatically. Regarding your conflict in the documentation, it is **only recommended not prohibited**. What they're trying to explain is that it works best if you treat the rb like a wrecking ball instead of tugging it in a direction. The reason you should put physics related stuff in `FixedUpdate`, since physics objects move every physics tick and your `Update` can thus run on inaccurate data.

Comment: @derHugo OP's setup is permanently kinematic, making the rigid body rather pointless.

Comment: Again, if it needs to be used with `OnTriggerEnter` / `OnCollisionEnter` at least one of the objects **NEEDS** to be a `Rigidbody` regardless whether it is forever kinematic or not -> [Collisions -> Collision Action Matrix](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CollidersOverview.html)

Comment: Accept the default `Rigidbody.isKinematic = false`. _Let Unity do physics with zero code._  Make a coffee.

Comment: @MickyD In certain game genres, such as action platformers, opting to use a kinematic rigidbody and writing a handful of custom physics methods can be preferable to fighting with the floaty, real world physics inherent to dynamic rigidbodies.

Comment: @GingerandLavender _”In certain game genres, such as action platformers”_ - one does not require a RigidBody for _Donkey Kong,_ kinematic-enabled or otherwise, just a simple lerp function.   Don’t overcomplicate it.